# Parsing Python Dictionary Keys

Tags: python, pickle

Is there way I can capture the full structure of a pickle dictionary?
If I have this pickle file:

```
{
    '9': {
        'Dual': {
            'spectrum' : ..., 
            'interferogram': ..., 
            'SNR': ...
         }, 
        'Top': {
            'spectrum' : ..., 
            'interferogram': ..., 
            'SNR': ...
         }, 
        'Bottom': {
            'spectrum' : ..., 
            'interferogram': ..., 
            'SNR': ...
         }
     }, 
     '10': ..., 
     '11': ...
}
```

What I want is a shortcut to look at all the keys in the pickle file without doing this:

```
lvl1 = dictionary.keys()
lvl2 = dictionary['9'].keys()
lvl3 = dictionary['9']['Dual'].keys()
```

**As I will not know the keys inside the pickle file ahead of time, but I will know there are 3 levels.**

I want to somehow get the different layers of the dictionary like this:

```
lvl1.keys() = {'9','10','11'}
lvl2.keys() = {'Dual', 'Top', 'Bottom'}
lvl3.keys() = {'spectrum', 'interferogram', 'SNR'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know that 9Dic, 10Dic, and 11Dic have the same keys?

Comment: I have edited to make it clearer what data structure you are getting at.

Comment: @akgill yes, they will have the same keys. Some may be empty if they do not exist. Ie. maybe 9 doesn't have SNR but 10 does. 9 will just have a "-" in SNR while 10 has a number.

Comment: Note that `x1`, `x2`, etc... as variable names is a common anti-pattern - you want a sequence like a list and then `levels[0]`, `levels[1]`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to assume the structure is the same all the way through, this has a natural recursive solution:

```
def layers(data):
    try:
        keys = [data.keys()]
    except ValueError:
        return
    rest = layers(next(iter(data.values())))
    return keys + rest if rest else keys
```

Or in 3.x:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping

def layers(data):
    if isinstance(data, Mapping):
        yield data.keys()
        yield from layers(next(data.values()))
```

The advantage to this solution is that it doesn't rely on you knowing the number of layers.

```
[{'9','10','11'}, {'Dual', 'Top', 'Bottom'}, {'spectrum', 'interferogram', 'SNR'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

If the keys are uniform at each level (e.g. 9 has the same keys as 10, Dual has the same keys as Top), you could do something like this:

```
lvl1 = dictionary.keys()
lvl2 = dictionary[lvl1[0]].keys()
lvl3 = dictionary[lvl1[0]][lvl2[0]].keys()
```

This wouldn't assume prior knowledge of the actual key values.

Comment: That sounds good. I was hoping for something like a pprint function, but that works. Thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there's a way to do this without traversing everything, but here's how you'd do that without too much code:

```
level_1_keys = [k1 for k1 in dictionary.keys()]
level_2_keys = []
level_3_keys = []
for v1 in dictionary.values():
    level_2_keys += [k2 for k2 in v1.keys()]
    for v2 in v.values():
        level_3_keys += [k3 for k3 in v2.keys()]
```

**EDIT:** Lattyware's recursive solution is pretty solid too and solves the problem more generally. You could do a general solution iteratively too with some fancy looping, but it would probably be overkill.